# Difference between isinstance(dataset, (list,)) and isinstance(dataset, list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. `isinstance(dataset, (list,))`
2. `isinstance(dataset, list)`

I know isinstance is used to find whether a particular variable belongs to that particular datatype or not
BUT CAN YOU PLEASE LET ME KNOW WHAT EXACTLY THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 1 AND 2 ABOVE MENTIONED

Comment: There isn't any. What makes you think there is?

Comment: `isinstance` allows you to check an instance against either a single class *or* a tuple of classes. In your first case your tuple contains only a single class, which is the same class specified in the second case. So as @MisterMiyagi said, there isn't any difference.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, this is not much of a difference. The first one is used when you're trying to determine whether or not an object belongs to any of the datatypes are presented in the tuple. Look at the example below:

```
a = [3, 3, 2]
# a object is an instance of class list or str?
print(isinstance(a, (list, str)))
# it is equivalent with 
print(isinstance(a, list) or isinstance(a, str))
```

output:

```
True
True
```

for more complement explanations refer to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp)!